# Laravel 7.x Encryption string length, AES-128-CBC

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how to find the maximum number of characters for encrypted data.
This is necessary to find the maximum number of characters in the table.
Laravel's version is 7.x and uses AES-128-CBC.

```
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
$encrypt = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-128-CBC');
dd($encrypt->encrypt('abcdefg'));
```

Comment: why? if you want to store a long encrypted data.. just use longtext, mediumtext or text in DB

Comment: @ZeroOne
How should I write it?